# Why is Jackson writing the same JSON key/value twice?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following setup with Jackson:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Sub1.class, name = "sub1"),
    @Type(value = Sub2.class, name = "sub2")
})
abstract class BaseClass {
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then for example, Sub1 looks like this:

```
public class Sub1 extends BaseClass {
    String other;

    public String getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(String o) {
        other = o;
    }
}
```

The setup is basically to allow parsing of json documents that contain different types of embedded elements. 
The parsing works, but when I want to write out a Sub1 instance, strangely enough the 'type' key is written twice to the generated JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Sub1 d = new Sub1();
d.setType("sub1");

mapper.writerFor(Sub1.class).writeValue(System.out, d);
```

The output I'm getting is:
{"type":"sub1","type":"sub1","other":null}

After some experimentation it seems that one of the 'type' entries is caused by

```
@Type(value = Sub1.class, name = "sub1")
```

while the other one comes from the 'type' attribute. Obviously I only need 'type' entry in the JSON. Does anyone know how to prevent this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a very similar setup except my `type` is an abstract method without a backing property. I have no duplicates. Would adding `@JsonIgnore` to the property help?

Comment: After some more experimentation I came to a similar conclusion, @TedTrippin - thanks! Basically I was able to just remove the type attribute from the BaseClass. On the JSON side the correct output is generated and correct input can be parsed. On the Java side instead of calling `getType()` I can simply call `instanceof` on the object to check out what type it is...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. The fix that seemed to work was using

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
```

instead, i.e. use an `include` of `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY`. This makes Jackson use the [AsExistingPropertyTypeSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsExistingPropertyTypeSerializer.html), which, if you follow the trail to [TypeSerializer#typeId(Object value, JsonToken valueShape)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer.html#typeId-java.lang.Object-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken-) in the code of Jackson, you'll see that that makes the serializer expect that the property is available as a regular POJO property because it uses [WritableTypId.Inclusion.PAYLOAD_PROPERTY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/WritableTypeId.Inclusion.html#PAYLOAD_PROPERTY) in this case.